# UIViewcontroller doesn't load subview(swift 3)

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3

I got the following setup in my Storyboard:

UIView -> UIScrollView->UIView(MyOwnView)

I have a UIViewController and added a UIScrollView and in the UIScrollView I added a UIView. This UIView is a custom UIView:

```
class MyOwnView: UIView {


    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code


       self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: (UIImage(named: "menschVorne")?.resize(CGSize(width: rect.width, height: rect.height)))!)
print("loaded")

    }
}
```

When I load the UIViewController there is no Image displayed. The draw(rect..) function get called when the UIViewController appear. Can someone help me?

Kinldy Regards!

Comment: Have you set `ContentSize` of your scrollView? See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html)

Comment: Yes this is all set up correct. I draw in this UIView. If I interact(tap on it) with the UIView the image appear correct.

Answer (score 0):

I could find a work around:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "menschVorne")?.resize(CGSize(width: rect.width, height: rect.height))
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)



            self.addSubview(imageView)
            imageView.center = self.center
self.sendSubview(toBack: imageView)
```

instead of

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: (UIImage(named: "menschVorne")?.resize(CGSize(width: rect.width, height: rect.height)))!)
```